# In the derivation of Kubo Formula for electrical conductivity, how we can calculate the perturbation term which is due to the total electric field?

Tags: electric-fields, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory

The perturbed Hamiltonian for the system can be taken as $H + V$, where $V$ is interaction between the total electric field and the particles of the system. In my calculation I need to find a form of the perturbation i.e electric field which has vector potential and current density in it.